# SOLR CLOUD error on looping through search result on 9.0 Update-1

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm trying to setup SOLR Cloud to work with my Sitecore 9.0 (Update-1) instance. I'm using 3 different VMs with [1-Zookeeper + 1-SOLR 6.6.2] configured on all machines.
I have added the following collection to the SOLR.

[image]

The following code snippet, I used in a sublayout to print all items with templatename “Person”.

```
var index = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var results = context.GetQueryable<Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem>()
        .Where(i => i.TemplateName == "Person");
            Response.Write("<h3>Search Results</h3><br />");
    Response.Write("<b>Total Item Count :: </b>" + results.Count());
    foreach (SearchResultItem searchResultItem in results)
    {

        Response.Write(searchResultItem.Path + "<br />");
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to print search result for the above code snippet, getting the 
 following error :-

```
5108 04:52:14 ERROR <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><bool name="zkConnected">true</bool><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">24</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">_templatename:(Person)</str><str name="fq">_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)</str><str name="rows">2147483647</str><str name="wt">xml</str><str name="version">2.2</str></lst></lst><lst name="error"><str name="trace">java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.&lt;init&gt;(PriorityQueue.java:63)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.&lt;init&gt;(PriorityQueue.java:44)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.&lt;init&gt;(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:45)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:991)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:775)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:754)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:429)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst>
</response>

Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><bool name="zkConnected">true</bool><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">24</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">_templatename:(Person)</str><str name="fq">_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)</str><str name="rows">2147483647</str><str name="wt">xml</str><str name="version">2.2</str></lst></lst><lst name="error"><str name="trace">java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.&lt;init&gt;(PriorityQueue.java:63)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.&lt;init&gt;(PriorityQueue.java:44)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.&lt;init&gt;(ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.java:45)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:991)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:775)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:754)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:429)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst>
</response>

Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrQueryExecuter`1.Execute(ISolrQuery q, QueryOptions options)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1.GetResult(SolrCompositeQuery compositeQuery, QueryOptions queryOptions)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

I am using Azure loadbalancer to connect to SOLR CLOUD. I'm able to successfully query on SOLR dashboard. But when I do a search query from my CD or CM envirnment,

```
Response.Write("<b>Total Item Count :: </b>" + results.Count());
```

It prints the total result count. But when the control enters the foreach loop, it throws the error.

```
foreach (SearchResultItem searchResultItem in results)
```

I believe the issue might be with SOLR Cloud configuration on distributed environment. How do I figure out what is wrong here? Thanks !

Comment: Where is ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress pointing to? Is it pointing to loadbalancer? If yes, can you browse to loadbalancer url and query the same way as in Solr dashboard?

Comment: Do you have a value for the setting `ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults` in your Sitecore config? I've had a problem very similar to this and it turned out that SearchMaxResults is int.Max unless defined in your config. Sending the int.Max  (2^31-1) value in queries to Solr gives all kinds of strange errors. If not set, set SearchMaxResults to something like 1000 or so.

Comment: the issue was with my loadbalancer configuration. It's resolved. Thank you all for the support.